# Install .exe's from different folders and add a switch

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I'm going to try and explain this the best I can!

This is my following folder structure ...

```
-MDT SERVER
 -Applications
  -Z30 Drivers
   -Driver Folder 1
    -Install.exe
   -Driver Folder 2
    -Install.exe
```

So, what I want to do is create a batch file that runs the .exe file from each folder (31 folders) but adds the -s switch e.g "install.exe -s".

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks.

Comment: Fine... and what is your *specific* question?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and we'll be able to assist you.

Comment: I wanted to create a script that runs though each file and installs the .exe with the "-s" script. I have now figured it out - here's my code. ECHO OFF

ECHO "INSTALLING DRIVER.. PLEASE WAIT"

forfiles /p "Z:\Applications\Z30 - App files" /m *.exe /s /c "cmd /c @FILE -S -SCM"

PAUSE

Answer (score 0):

not tested

```
@echo off
cd "mdt server"

for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
  pushd %%a
  install.exe -s
  popd
)
```